# Using Resource files for things other than language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, globalization

I am working on an MVC application that is effectively a piece of middleware to provide admin and reporting on an external BPM solution.

The users of the system aren't all for the same business function and may refer to fields as different things (e.g. division A calls a client a Client but division B calls them a Prospect). Is there a way I could have resource files for

- Resources.divA.resx
- Resources.divB.resx
- Resources.divC.resx

From my googling, it appears it can only be used for localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ResourceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Resources.ResourceManager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to help with this.

When you add some resources to a project, the IDE automatically adds a `Resources.Designer.cs` file to the project to manage the resources. The generated code looks something like this:

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("AssemblyName.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
        }
        return resourceMan;
    }
}
```

This uses [the ResourceManager constructor that looks up resources based on a combination of a root name and the current locale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can write similar code yourself, but compute a root name based on whether the the resources are for division A, B or C. So you would call it something like "AssemblyName.Resources.divA" instead of "AssemblyName.Properties.Resources".

You can then also have specific versions for each other supported language and they will be automatically loaded (if present) for the current culture. This is how it works for the IDE-managed resources.